# Getting 404 upon splitting up a file in flask

Tags: python-2.7, flask, http-status-code-404

My flask app runs fine.
But, when I split it up into 3 parts, the imported one displays a 404.

Here is the file structure:

```
myproject/
     run.py  
     appy/
         __init__.py
         index.py
```

.

```
#run.py

from appy import app
if __name__ == '__main__
     app.run()
```

.

```
#__init.py  

from flask import Flask
app = Flask('appy')

from appy import index  

@app.route("/h")
def hello():
  return "Hello"
```

.

```
#index.py

from appy import app

@app.route("/s")
def shello():
  return "Shello"
```

`localhost/h` runs fine returning Hello.
`localhost/s` gives 404.

Also, everything runs fine when merged into a single file.
Please suggest a way to do it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into a circular import error. You are importing **app into index.py** but you are also importing **index.py into __init__.py**.

If you want to have everything in a different file the best way to do it is make your **init**.py file empty, and create a differently named file for the contents of index.py

Then from your new "**init**.py" file (with a new name) import the contents of index, and then run the app.

Should work now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sir ! It worked. I had heard about circular imports, but, today I ran into it. I emptied my `__init__.py`, moved its contents into a new file `new.py` in appy folder, and finally imported `index.py` into this newly created `new.py`, and it worked. Thanks again :)